# multer is not working in my app

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I am trying to upload a file. The file does not get uploaded and multer does not give me any errors.
**app.js**

```
var uploadDir=__dirname+'/uploads';
var storage=multer.diskStorage({
  destination:function(req, file, cb){
      cb(null, uploadDir);
  },
  filename:function(req, file, cb){
    console.log(file);
    var ext=".jpg";
    var image=Date.now()+ext;
    cb(null, image);
  }
});

var upload=multer({storage:storage}).single('img');
```

and route where I am using Multer

```
apiRoutes.post('/cc', upload, function(req, res, next){
console.log("Image Saved Successfully");
});
```

This is working in my last project but its not working in current project. Even its not going on console line. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I am having the same experience, was there a breaking change that anyone knows about? I've tried the accepted solutions from other posts and none are working, I've even copied the example from the multer git page and it doesn't work for me either. I've set the headers as suggested. No matter, doesn't work. I'm at a loss, and I'm going to try another library now.

Comment: @Porlune Are you using angular at the front side??? If yes then u hv to handle uploaded File by angular and then send it to node.js server... That was the issue  which I was facing.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but I think my problem was that postman just was having trouble with the image I was choosing as a test, after changing the image it seems to be working now. I don't know why it took me an hour of pulling out my hair before I just tried changing the file. The magic of asking solved things :)

Comment: Woooowww....cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, i dont have enough reputation to comment, but are you uploading via a html form?

If so, did you ensure that the form has enctype attribute of 'multipart/form-data'?

I have an example of using multer with html form + jquery ajax in the link below::
https://github.com/Wotzhs/node-image-zip-uploader/blob/master/public/js/index.js

Comment: no...nothing is happening... compiler is not executing `destination` and `filename` functions. Even console is also not executing which is in `filename` function.

Comment: do you mind to include how you upload your file? if it's via ajax then you need to specify the `contentType = false` & `processData = false`